# Problems with trigonometric functions in Visual Studio

Tags: vbscript

I have recently started coding using visual basic and have created a moderately good, functional calculator.

The only problem is the trigonometric functions. The answer visual basic gives me when I do the sine of 90(0.893...) is completely different to the one my calculator gives me (1).

I am really confused as to what this is and i was wandering if this was a setting on visual studio that i could change so that it is the same as my calculator.

Also the same with the inverse functions, giving me completely different answers to those of my calculator although it does match with the sine function that visual basic tells me.

Comment: You probably need to convert your angles from degrees to radians, before calling the trig functions.

Comment: Have you converted angles to radians? All VBScript trigonometry functions use radians as input.

Comment: how do i convert them?